# How can i get a derived class data member via base class pointer (upcasting)

Tags: c++

```
class Base{
common methods
};
class Derived: public Base{
private: 
int a;
char* arr;
public: 
Ctor
Dtor
};

int main(){
Base* B;
Derived D;
B = &D;
```

how can i extract information from B about D's data members?

don't mind the syntax error, I'm more concerned about how to get the data members or how to comper two derived classes if I have more then one derived class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you know that the pointee is a `Derived`, then you can **downcast** the pointer from `Base*` to `Derived*`, preferably by using a `static_cast`. When you don't know, but the base class has one or more virtual methods, then you can *check* via `dynamic_cast`. But preferably you should have virtual methods in `Base` so that you can do whatever it is without casting, or else, you should ideally not be throwing away the specific type information in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the dynamic_cast, but I thought there is a simpler way (because I'm a student and I have to make a program with 5 derived classes and even multiple inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

you will first need to cast it to the derived type:

assume v2 is a string member of the Derived class

```
if (auto* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(B))
    std::cout << "v2: " << d->v2 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define virtual function in Base then implement it in Derive class. Does it help?

Comment: No, in my case I have a lot of derived classes, so even if something like virtual get () method will work, I have a lot of different members in each derived class.